# How to change the value of nested span using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the value of the span using jquery in the following code.

I tried this but unable to change the value.

```js
$(".bootstraplist span").text("Change value");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/">

<div class="custom-form bootstraplist">

  <select class="chosen-select" id="bootstrap_version" data-placeholder="Bootstrap Version" style="display: none;">
    <option value="8">Example 1</option>
    <option value="5">Example 2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="nice-select chosen-select" tabindex="0">
    <span class="current">Bootstrap 5 - 5.0.0</span>
    <div class="nice-select-search-box"><input type="text" class="nice-select-search" placeholder="Search..."></div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li data-value="8" class="option selected">Bootstrap 5 - 5.0.0</li>
      <li data-value="7" class="option">Bootstrap 4 - 4.4.1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works. I made you a snippet. You have to load jQuery. Please look in the console and network tab for errors or 404s

Comment: Not working... and not getting any error too

Comment: See the snippet. It works just fine. There is some other issue - are you loading jQuery and did you spell the classname correctly?

Answer (score -1):

try:

$(".bootstraplist").find("span").text("Change value");